# Deposit Money Automatically On Child Creation In Factory Pattern

Tags: solidity, remix, constructor, factory

I am implementing a factory pattern contract and on my constructor I want to deposit money into my child contract as soon as the child is rendered

--Factory--

```
function newChild() {
     Child child = new Child(money);
}
```

--Child Contract--

```
address payable public spender;

constructor(uint256 _money) {
   address(this).transfer(_money) /*{from: spender}*/;
}
```

My remix IDE is yelling at me that transfer is only valid on address of type payable. Obviously I am doing something quite wrong here so my question is what is the best way to send money immediately when I child is created?

Also I want to spend that money from a specific address lets call it the spender for now. How do I sent the money from that address

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A contract only can spend its own ether. It cannot access funds from another address.

The following code should do something similar.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.7.4;

contract Factory {
    event NewChild(address child);

    // Make function payable to accept ethers on invocation
    function newChild(uint256 param) public payable {

        // Forward ethers received by function to Child
        Child cld = new Child{value: msg.value}(param);

        emit NewChild(address(cld));
    }
}

contract Child {
    uint256 public id;

    // Make constructor payable to receive ethers on creation
    constructor(uint256 param) public payable {
        id = param;
    }
}
```